# Compilation Error: StanfordCoreNLP cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, stanford-nlp

I downloaded the latest version of StanfordCoreNLP (2015-12-09 ver 3.6.0). I created a project in Eclipse and wrote a simple class to test the tools out. I made sure to add all the jar files to the classpath.

[image: classpath structure]

And here's the simple demo code im testing.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeCoreAnnotations.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations;

public class second_test 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
{   

    PrintWriter xmlOut = new PrintWriter("xmlOutput.xml");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators","tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation("Demo sentence for testing.");
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    pipeline.xmlPrint(annotation, xmlOut);
    // An Annotation is a Map and you can get and use the
    // various analyses individually. For instance, this
    // gets the parse tree of the 1st sentence in the text.
    List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);

    if (sentences != null && sentences.size() > 0) 
    {
        CoreMap sentence = sentences.get(0);
        Tree tree = (Tree)sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        out.println("The first sentence parsed is:");
        tree.pennPrint(out);
    }
}
}
```

When I run this code, I can see some errors in the console.

1) First error occurs when the object "pipeline" is declared: StanfordCoreNLP cannot be resolved to a type .

2) Second error occurs when the object "sentences" is declared: Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater
    The type edu.stanford.nlp.util.ArrayCoreMap cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    The method get(Class) is undefined for the type Annotation

Any ideas to resolve this error would be appreciated.

Comment: ok. Check the eclipse for which version of compiler it is using?

Comment: updated eclipse and changed compliance settings to fix these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the fix was simple enough.

1) I updated to the latest version of Eclipse and that fixed the first issue.
2) To fix the second issue, I went to Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler. I clicked the "Enable Project Specific Settings" and set the compiler compliance level to 1.5.

Moral of the story: Have the latest version of tools to build things.